# Insert or Update Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure to insert or update a em table in a database like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInsertorUpdateArchibusINF]
@em_TT AS em_TT READONLY
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  UPDATE e
     SET e.dp_id                 = t.dp_id,
         e.dv_id                 = t.dv_id,
         e.email                 = t.email,
         e.emergency_relation    = t.emergency_relation,
         e.name_first            = t.name_first,
         e.name_last             = t.name_last,
         e.option1               = t.option1,
         e.status                = t.status,
         e.em_title              = t.em_title,
         e.date_hired            = t.date_hired
    FROM [dbo].[em] e 
    INNER JOIN @em_TT t ON e.em_id = t.em_id

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[em](dp_id, dv_id, email, emergency_relation, name_first,name_last
                                    , option1, status, em_id, em_title,date_hired)
  SELECT t.dp_id, t.dv_id, t.email
        , t.emergency_relation,t.name_first,t.name_last, t.option1, t.status
        , t.em_id, t.em_title, t.date_hired
  FROM @em_TT t 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM [dbo].[em]
                    WHERE em_id = t.em_id)
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END;
```

Where dp_id and dv_id in em table are the foreign keys from the table dv and dp. So now I try inserting some new values in to em table it throws error like 
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "em_dp_id". The conflict occurred in database "j20", table "dbo.dp".

No I am not sure if I can modify te above stored procedure to insert if there is a new dp_id or dv_id in to respective tables. Or do I have to create it seperately. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could add the insert to the other table in this stored proc if you will have the information you would need to do the insert.  If that table has 12 required fields and you only know the name of the id, then no you can't do it here.  But if all that goes into that table are say the id and a start-date, yes you could. Whether you would want to is another issue discussed below.

The business rules that your company sets will dictate whether it is a good idea to insert into that table at this point.  You may have a case where certain ids are not supposed to be supported by your application.  (In our case we sometimes support some but not all sales forces of a client, for example.) In this case, it would be a bad idea to insert even if you have all the data you need. It could be that this information must come only from an approved source and then this insert again would be the wrong place. These are questions that strangers on the Internet can't answer, you must consult the people who give you requirements.

Another possibility is that you join to the table in doing the insert so that you don't get the error. This is what you would want to do if, you are not supposed to insert to the parent table. I personally would suggest implementing this with an exception table where I inserted the ones that can't be inserted or have them filter up to the user at the time they are rejected. A lot of this depends on how your whole system works and whether these are coming from users or file imports.

As an aside, your update is flawed in that it updates every single record of the table based on the join instead of any that are changed from he existing data. Depending on how many records that is, it could be a performance issue. Updating ten records unnecessarily, no big deal, updating 10,000,000? Could be a problem.